# HTML Bootstrap one set of images overlap and similar code for a second set do not

Tags: java, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have very similar HTML and Bootstrap to display two sets of images. However, the fist set of images overlap and the second set display correctly and do not overlap. Can anyone spot the reason please?

I am still learning so any other comments greatly appreciated.

I generate the HTML in java and pass it back to the HTML page via AJAX.

The HTML page is:

```
  <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="six">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-select">
                        <!-- Place for Six image and date -->
                        <div class="input-group" id="img-six">
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="selectAward">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-select">
                        <!-- Place for Award image -->
                        <div class="input-group" id="img-container2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The first JAVA (which overlaps) is:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Get the Youth Member ID
    ymID = request.getParameter("ssYMID"); // From Local Storage

    byte[] valueDecoded= Base64.decodeBase64(ymID);//decoding part
    String decoded_id = new String(valueDecoded);

    //Get Six details
    List<YthMmbrSixDtls> ymSixList = MySQLConnection.getYthMmbrSixDtls(decoded_id, "Cub");

    String json = null;
    int i = 0;
    int col = 1;

    if (!ymSixList.isEmpty()) {
        for (final YthMmbrSixDtls ymSix : ymSixList) {
            String image = ymSix.getSixPicture();

            byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(ymSix.getYmSixId().getBytes());//encoding part
            String encoded_six_ID = new String(bytesEncoded);

            if (i == 0){
                //Youth encrypted member ID is stored in session storage - ssYMID
                //The encrypted Award ID is: encoded_award_ID
                //Selecting the picture will display the requirements for the Award
                //Updating the date under the Award will be saved to the database for that Award
                json = "<h3>Six</h3>";
                json = json + "<div class='row'>";
                json = json + "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>";
                json = json + "<a href='UpdateYMSixPatrol.html'>";
                json = json + "<img src=" + image + " height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image' />";
                json = json + "</a>";
                json = json + "<div class='caption'>";
                json = json + "<p>";
                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='sixDate' id='sixDate' value='" + ymSix.getYmSixStartDate() + "' onchange='sixDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_six_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;'/>";

                json = json + "</p>";
                json = json + "</div>";
                json = json + "</div>";
                i++; col++;
            }else{
                if (col > 12){
                    json = json + "</div>";
                    json = json + "<div class='row'>";
                    col = 1;
                }
                json = json + "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>";
                json = json + "<a href='UpdateYMSixPatrol.html'>";
                json = json + "<img src=" + image + " height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image' />";
                json = json + "</a>";
                json = json + "<div class='caption'>";
                json = json + "<p>";
                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='sixDate' id='sixDate' value='" + ymSix.getYmSixStartDate() + "' onchange='sixDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_six_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;'/>";
                json = json + "</p>";
                json = json + "</div>";
                json = json + "</div>";
                col++;
            }
        }
        if (col > 0){
            json = json + "</div>";
        }
    }else{
        json = "<h3>Six</h3>";
        json = json + "<div class='row'>";
        json = json + "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>";
        json = json + "<a href='UpdateYMSixPatrol.html'>";
        json = json + "<img src=images/SixAssignment.gif height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image'/>";
        json = json + "</a>";
        json = json + "</div>";
        json = json + "</div>";
    }
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

The second JAVA (which displays correctly) is:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Get the Youth Member ID from local storage
    encoded_ymID = request.getParameter("ssYMID");
    section = request.getParameter("ssGroupSection");

    //Decrypt variables
    byte[] valueDecoded1 = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded_ymID);//decoding part
    String ymID = new String(valueDecoded1);

    //Get Youth Member Image
    List<YouthMemberAwards> youthMemberAwards = MySQLConnection.ymAwardsList(ymID, section);

    String json = null;
    String awardType2 = null;
    int i = 0;
    int col = 1;

    for (final YouthMemberAwards youthMemberAward : youthMemberAwards) {
        String image = youthMemberAward.getAwAwardPicture();

        byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(youthMemberAward.getAwId().getBytes());//encoding part
        String encoded_award_ID = new String(bytesEncoded);

        if (i == 0){
            awardType2 = youthMemberAward.getAwAwardType();
            //Youth encrypted member ID is stored in session storage - ssYMID
            //The encrypted Award ID is: encoded_award_ID
            //Selecting the picture will display the requirements for the Award
            //Updating the date under the Award will be saved to the database for that Award
            json = "<h3>" + awardType2 + "</h3>";
            json = json + "<div class='row'>";
            json = json + "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>";
            json = json + "<a href='CubAwardOverview.html?id=" + encoded_award_ID + "'>";
            json = json + "<img src=" + image + " height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image' />";
            json = json + "</a>";
            json = json + "<div class='caption'>";
            json = json + "<p>";
            if(section.equals("Joey") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#C86C43;'/>";
            }else{
                if(section.equals("Cub") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                    json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#FFCC05;'/>";
                }else{
                    if(section.equals("Scout") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                        json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#0F640C;'/>";
                    }else{
                        if(section.equals("Venturer") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                            json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#4F060A;'/>";
                        }else{
                            if(section.equals("Rover") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#9A050D;'/>";
                            }else{
                                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;'/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            json = json + "</p>";
            json = json + "</div>";
            json = json + "</div>";
            i++; col++;
        }else{
            if (awardType2.equals(youthMemberAward.getAwAwardType())){
                if (col > 12){
                    json = json + "</div>";
                    json = json + "<div class='row'>";
                    col = 1;
                }
            }else{
                awardType2 = youthMemberAward.getAwAwardType();
                json = json + "</div>";
                json = json + "<div class='row'>";
                json = json + "<h3>" + awardType2 + "</h3>";
                json = json + "</div>";
                json = json + "<div class='row'>";
                col = 1;
            }
            json = json + "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>";
            json = json + "<a href='CubAwardOverview.html?id=" + encoded_award_ID + "'>";
            json = json + "<img src=" + image + " height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image' />";
            json = json + "</a>";
            json = json + "<div class='caption'>";
            json = json + "<p>";
            if(section.equals("Joey") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#C86C43;'/>";
            }else{
                if(section.equals("Cub") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                    json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#FFCC05;'/>";
                }else{
                    if(section.equals("Scout") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                        json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#0F640C;'/>";
                    }else{
                        if(section.equals("Venturer") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                            json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#4F060A;'/>";
                        }else{
                            if(section.equals("Rover") && youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;background-color:#9A050D;'/>";
                            }else{
                                json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='awardDateUpdateFunction(this.value, \"" + encoded_award_ID.replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\")' style='width:160px;'/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            json = json + "</p>";
            json = json + "</div>";
            json = json + "</div>";
            col++;
        }
    }
    if (col > 0){
        json = json + "</div>";
    }
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

The CSS is:

```
.form-select {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  }
```

This image shows the two results:

[image]

Comment: Is there any CSS to go with this?

Comment: Can you check in console that all the opening html tags have their closing tags as well. For eg: <div>//Content</div>

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have added the CSS applicable. I have also desk checked the opening and closing tags.